# How can i export axios post method in javascript file to vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, axios

I'm having trouble exporting the data I got from the api in my javascript file and displaying it in my vue file.

I am sending security json to server with post method. I get the output with console log. but I want to show the data in my vue file instead of outputting it.

I tried something like this:

dataAdvancedTable.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const data = JSON.stringify({
    "guvenlik_bir": 111,
    "guvenlik_iki": 111111
});

const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://altayapi.altaydigital.com/api/blog/list',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data : data
};

axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

export default data;
```

list.vue

```
<script>
import Layout from "../../layouts/main";
import PageHeader from "@/components/page-header";
import appConfig from "@/app.config";

import data from "./dataAdvancedtable";

/**
 * All Posts component
 */
export default {
  page: {
    title: "All Posts",
    meta: [{ name: "description", content: appConfig.description }]
  },
  components: { Layout, PageHeader },
  data() {
    return {
      data: data,
      title: "All Posts",
      items: [
        {
          text: "Blog",
          href: "/"
        },
        {
          text: "All Posts",
          active: true
        }
      ],
      totalRows: 1,
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 10,
      pageOptions: [10, 25, 50, 100],
      filter: null,
      filterOn: [],
      sortDesc: false,
      fields: [
        { key: "selected" },
        { key: "title", sortable: true },
        { key: "body", sortable: true },
        { key: "category", sortable: true },
        { key: "date", sortable: true },
        { key: "actions", label: "Actions" }
      ],
      selectMode: 'multi',
      selected: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    /**
     * Total no. of records
     */
    rows() {
      return this.data; // this.data.length;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Set the initial number of items
    this.totalRows = this.items.length;
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Search the table data with search input
     */
    onFiltered(filteredItems) {
      // Trigger pagination to update the number of buttons/pages due to filtering
      this.totalRows = filteredItems.length;
      this.currentPage = 1;
    },
    onRowSelected(items) {
        this.selected = items
      },
      selectAllRows() {
        this.$refs.selectableTable.selectAllRows()
      },
      clearSelected() {
        this.$refs.selectableTable.clearSelected()
      },
      selectThirdRow() {
        // Rows are indexed from 0, so the third row is index 2
        this.$refs.selectableTable.selectRow(2)
      },
      unselectThirdRow() {
        // Rows are indexed from 0, so the third row is index 2
        this.$refs.selectableTable.unselectRow(2)
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

console output:

```
{"blogs":[{"id":1,"title":"title","slug":"slug","description":"description","text":"text","image":null,"categori":1,"read":2,"created_at":"2022-10-27T08:28:22.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-10-27T08:51:46.000000Z","deleted_at":null,"find_categori":null}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the names of the files.

list.vue

> import data from "./dataAdvancedtable";

Comment: Some clarification would be nice. How, What, Why... (See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)